# Shouldn't CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::get localize parameter be setted to TRUE by default?

Tags: best-practice, localisation

Some translations are missing in non-english language (french in my case), because of the fact that localize's parameter is set to FALSE by default with no way to change it via configuration.

So my question is why that ? And not the opposite ? And best of all why not when the language is not english set localize to TRUE.

Comment: I suspect it's because of old legacy reasons. Can you give an example of a form/page where the translation was missing?

Comment: When you manage a client case, the url should be like "/civicrm/contact/view/case?action=view". The status isn't translated by default and when you click to select another value it is the same

Comment: The functions are called in CRM_Core_PseudoConstant line 221 and 1520 on civicrm 4.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case statuses are user-defined option values (configurations). If you have installed CiviCRM initially in English, then switched the language, you will have to edit/translate the case statuses manually in: Administer > Case > Case statuses (/civicrm/admin/options/case_status?reset=1).

Comment: Actually my problem isn't on Case statuses but most likely Activity statuses. So I did the same on Activity statuses and everything's good ! Thank's a lot bgm for taking the time to answer me !!